# Use kafkacat to see header but throws % ERROR: Unsupported formatter: %h

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

I use kafkacat to see the header, but it returns

```
 % ERROR: Unsupported formatter: %h
```

My kafkacat is 1.3, installed by `apt-get install kafkacat`

The full command I use is:

```sh
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t dlq_file_sink_03 -C -o-1 -c1 \
  -f '\nKey (%K bytes): %k
  Value (%S bytes): %s
  Timestamp: %T
  Partition: %p
  Offset: %o
  Headers: %h\n'
```

The above works without %h. %H also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This was added to `kafkacat` in recent versions. If the version you have does not support it the your other option is to [build it yourself](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat#build) or run the [Docker image](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat#running-in-docker).

Comment: is the reading header feature included in the latest docker image? I tested days ago but it didn't work. I may try specifying 5.2.2 later.

Comment: when building kafkacat locally by running `make` after `configure` success, it returns
```
kafkacat.h:105:9: error: unknown type name ‘rd_kafka_headers_t’
         rd_kafka_headers_t *headers;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 mklove/Makefile.base:77: recipe for target 'kafkacat.o' failed
make: *** [kafkacat.o] Error 1
 ```

Comment: @AkiraSendoh You need to upgrade librdkafka (to v0.11.6 or later, preferably v1.1.0).

Comment: Or you could try the latest docker image: `docker run -it --net=host edenhill/kafkacat:20190709  ... `

Comment: @Edehill thank you! the container works. I found this version cannot use `-C -o-5` and has to use -G? but I don't find a way to use -G that reads from the beginning. do I have to create a consumer group pointing to the earliest offset in advance?

Comment: thanks edenhill for the help in the github issue! following is the solution from him:


docker run --tty --interactive --rm --net=host \
                  edenhill/kafkacat:20190709 \
                  -b localhost:29092 -t kafkacat -o beginning \
   -f '\n Value (%S bytes): %s Headers: %h\n' 


https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/issues/191